# How to scrape a dictionary into a link?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm training to scrape with BS4 for my school, and want to extract content of a dictionary from a link anchor . How can I extract content of the dictionary `ctdata`?

Following are the details:

The link: `a ct="result_offer_content"`

```
ctdata = {"ad_id_solr": "1a7d243c3610c62012159b7c9d4e900382bbe446", 
  "ad_id_mongo": "", "ad_segment_id": 1723, "ad_partner": "wizbii.com_premium",  
  "ad_sector": "Ing\u00e9nierie", "ad_subsector": "", 
  "ad_jobtitle": "Ing\u00e9nieur d\u00e9veloppeur", "ad_company": "SII",
  "ad_type": "exact", "ad_position": 1, "ad_locality": "Bordeaux"}
```

I've tried

```
for offers in soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'}):
   offre = offers.find('ctdata')
   print(jobtitle)
```

but output is 'None None ....'

Comment: You'll end up reading that in as a json format. Is it possible for you to include the code prior to this? Include the `requests.get()` with the url, and `soup = BeautifulSoup()` etc. It would just be easier to see exactly the data response you're talking about

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML your trying to scrape or at least the web page you are scraping?

Comment: Thank you. this is my training page : req = requests.get("https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/query/?what=data&where=Bordeaux&where_type=city")

Answer (score 1):

That would be read in as json since it's in a json structure. I am a little confussed though as to what `jobtitle` is referencing as you haven't supplied to full code. And also since the full code is not here, I can only offer a general solution, so you will need to adapt, but this is how you would read that in:

```
import json

json_str = '{"ad_id_solr":"1a7d243c3610c62012159b7c9d4e900382bbe446","ad_id_mongo":"","ad_segment_id":1723,"ad_partner":"wizbii.com_premium","ad_sector":"Ing\u00e9nierie","ad_subsector":"","ad_jobtitle":"Ing\u00e9nieur d\u00e9veloppeur","ad_company":"SII","ad_type":"exact","ad_position":1,"ad_locality":"Bordeaux"}'

json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
```

**ADDITIONAL**

Now that you have supplied the url, I was able to see the issue. You want to use `.get()` not `.find` for the attribute `'ctdata'`

```
import json
import requests
import bs4


req = requests.get("https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/query/?what=data&where=Bordeaux&where_type=city%22")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

offers = soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'})

for offers in soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'}):
    offre = offers.get('ctdata')

    json_dict = json.loads(offre)
    jobtitle = json_dict['ad_jobtitle']
    print (jobtitle)
```

**Output:**

```
Ingénieur développeur

Ingénieur développeur
Data Scientist
Data Scientist

Développeur big data


Data Scientist
Data Scientist

Ingénieur développeur
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Data Scientist



Ingénieur décisionnel

Architecte
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Data Scientist

Développeur informatique
```

Some of the tags do not have a job title with it, so you can essentially skip those/not print them out by checking if job title is blank:

```
import json
import requests
import bs4


req = requests.get("https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/query/?what=data&where=Bordeaux&where_type=city%22")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

offers = soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'})

for offers in soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'}):
    offre = offers.get('ctdata')

    json_dict = json.loads(offre)
    jobtitle = json_dict['ad_jobtitle']
    if jobtitle != '':
        print (jobtitle)
```

**Output:**

```
Ingénieur développeur
Ingénieur développeur
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Développeur big data
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Ingénieur développeur
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Ingénieur décisionnel
Architecte
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Data Scientist
Développeur informatique
```

Comment: thanks.I add this code :

    for offers in soup.find_all("a", {'ct':'result_offer_content'}):
        jobtitle = json.loads(offers.find('ctdata'))
        print(jobtitle)

I still have a TypeError because of Nonetype

Comment: "You want to use .get() not .find for the attribute 'ctdata'"